# Facebook graph api post a sell post on facebook group's wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

After reading Graph API documentation, stackoverflow questions, etc, i'm still confused on the task i have.

**In short what i want:**

-i have a classified ads website and i want to publish the ad from it to a facebook group where i'm not an administrator.
I have a facebook page (which is represent my website) from the name of which i want to publish an ad in the group. The ad in the group must be published as the "sale" post.

I'm using Facebook javascript SDK for this.

So, i'm really stuck in how do i do it.

what i tried is publishing using my app, using user/page access_token, but always getting different problems.

Can someone tell me, if it is possible to make what i want? and if possible - the algorhytm, what should i do for that?

Comment: There is no way to create sales posts via API.

Comment: Is it still not possible?

Comment: I am in the same situation for the same exact problem. Your post describes 100% of what I had in mind. Do you have any updates on this?

Comment: Hi! unfortunately i had to make a workaround to automate it - selenium-based emulation by using a pool of FB accounts (with the private proxy for each).

Comment: @user1935987 Can you share some sample code? I love Selenium :) We are having a small farm of servers doing auto. tests...

Comment: @TimLong sorry i don't think so - the solution i've made for it is quite huge & complex => don't think possible to show it here anyhow. Publishing small pieces of code isn't gonna explain it all.

Comment: @user1935987 I've got mine now! Trying to push it to the cloud :)

Comment: @user1935987 How about your timing, time-period, when to start, stop, pause the auto. tests...? I'm afraid, FB will notice and block if we just start the test straight off insanely :)

Comment: @TimLong Simply randomize it.